# Magento WSI SOAP v2 API Custom Webservice Returns Empty Response

Tags: api, magento, soap

Problem: I succesfully call my webservice, but I get an empty response in return.

Situation:

- I created a new Module structure and files following this tutorial: [Magento: Extending the API (v2)](http://www.tall-paul.co.uk/2012/04/04/magento-extending-the-api-v2/)

  - MyNamespace

    - MyModule

      - Helper

        - Data.php
      - Model

        - MyModel

          - Api

            - V2.php
        - etc

          - api.xml
          - config.xml
          - wsdl.xml
          - wsi.xml

Also added the module config in: app/etc/modules/MyNamespace_MyModule.xml

- I debug the call with XDebug, and effectively stops at the breakpoint inside the webservice function
- The webservice is supposed to return a simple string: "Hello World"
- Testing with SoapUI all I get is an empty response with content length 0.

What can be wrong or missing!? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I've managed to debug the call and realized that **when it reaches class Zend_Soap_Server on line 832**:

`$soap->handle($request);`

**It doesn't execute any further!** I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wsdl.xml had a small mis-configuration in the following line:

```
<binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
```

It should be:

```
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
```